# Bootstrap <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fixed, navbar

I am trying to built a site with Bootstrap. So far everything is going pretty much as planned. I would like a fixed navbar and I am using the built in function:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

This is great and just what I need BUT I would like the navigation and title to start at the same place as the container instead of all the way to the left/right (still having the navbar going 100% in width. I have tried to put a container inside the navbar which was not the correct solution :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### example

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="./index.html">Bootstrap</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="./getting-started.html">Get started</a>
              </li>

              ...

              <li>
                <a href="./customize.html">Customize</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

or throw

```
.navbar { 
    max-width: 1170px; /* width of .container */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

into the css

Comment: Hi Austin. This works like a charm! I have tried the container inside the menu without luck, may have put them on the wrong side of the navbar-inner??? Anyway... perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a container class nested inside your navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">your menu and logo go here</div>
</div>
```

That will give you the same width as the body container if you do not have a fluid layout and will give auto margins to the container so it is centered in the middle of the screen. It will also keep the navbar itself at 100%