# How to keep menu attached constantly to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.0. When I am scrolling down in mobile view the menu getting popup back to the top only after a few scrolls. Is there any fix to that?

1) Initial view (menu attached to top):

[image]

2) A few scrolls-down view (need to display menu on the top)
[image]

3) A few more scrolls (menu back again)

[image]

I believe there is somewhere in css some kind of rule saying to display menu when minimum scroll reached to some value, so i probably need to decrease that value or something?
I need it attached to the top only in mobile view but not on desktop or tablet views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using css. Where you should make nav bar positioning fixed.

Build in class for fixed nav to the top in bootrstap can be achieved using `navbar-fixed-top` class. Usage of 'navbar-fixed-top' can be founded [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). Or you can use following example.

```
.nav
{
   position: fixed;
}
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

P.S. My suggestion is just use built in class or CSS. But you can do it with other technique also.

Comment: Is there a rule in css what making current behaviour? I need it fixed only in mobile view but not on desktop view.

Comment: Of course it is is possible. Use media queries for this purpose. Read about media queries [here][1].

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I guess the query causing current behavior is already sitting bootstrap css?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533106/bootstrap-div-class-navbar-navbar-fixed-top) is similar question.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap has a built in javascript for that exact situation

heres and example for navbar:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy